# Understanding the exactness of a sequence in Kummer Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, exact-sequence, kummer-theory

Here are the prerequisites and the parts which cause me trouble (taken from [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)):

[image]

In particular, I don't quite understand the exactness at $H^1(G,\mu_n)$ and what it has to do with Hilbert 90 (as mentioned in the text).

If I understood the underlying maps correctly, the map $F^\times \cap E^{\times n} \to H^1(G,\mu_n)$ maps an element $z \in F^\times \cap E^{\times n}$ to the crossed homomorphism $f_z: G \to \mu_n$, $\sigma \mapsto \frac{\sigma(c)}{c}$ for an arbitrary $c \in E^\times$ with $z = c^n$ (one can show that the maps do not depend of the choice of $c$).

We can see here that $f_z$ is a principal crossed homomorphism, so the image of $F^\times \cap E^{\times n} \to H^1(G,\mu_n)$ is trivial. However, this seems to contradict the exactness because the kernel of $H^1(G,\mu_n) \to 1$ is obviously $H^1(G,\mu_n)$ which is not trivial.

And then, I still don't see what all of this has to do with Hilbert 90. Hilbert 90 says that if the norm of an element $\alpha \in E$ is $1$, then there exists a $\beta \in E$ such that $\alpha = \beta/\sigma(\beta)$ (where $\sigma$ is a generator of the Galois group of $E/F$).

Could you please resolve any misunderstandings I have here? Thank you!

Comment: Look at the definition of coboundary $B^1(G, M)$, you need $\xi_\sigma = \sigma(m)/m$ for some $m \in M$ -  in your example $c$ does not live in $\mu_n$. One statement of Hilbert 90 is that $H^1(G, E^\times) = 1$.

Comment: I'd also say that considering how useful cohomology is, this is the Hilbert 90 worth remembering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hilbert 90 has two common formulations -- one is the form you are quoting (where it is only valid if $E/F$ is a cyclic extension, by the way), and the other says $H^1(\text{Gal}(E/F), E^\times) = 0$ (any $E/F$ Galois -- this can be translated to your cyclic example by using an explicit description of the cohomology of cyclic groups).

Now if we take your short exact sequence, we get a long exact sequence in cohomology. The next term after $H^1(G, \mu_n)$ is $H^1(G, E^\times)$, which vanishes by Hilbert 90.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you please elaborate the part how one gets from the short exact sequence to this sequence in cohomology? This seems to sound like a general concept but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @Ribbity  Quite generally, if $G$ is a group and you have a short exact sequence $ 0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \ to 0$ of $G$-modules, then you have a long exact sequene $0 \to (M')^G \to M^G \to (M'')^G \to H^1(G, M') \to H^1(G, M) \to \ldots$. You can check that that's what's going on in your example.

Comment: What comes after the last $\to$? It seems like something is missing there. Or in this case, the last $\to$ was a typo?

Comment: @Ribbity: the sequence continues infinitely. The next term is $H^1(G, M'')$, then the term after that is $H^2(G, M')$, etc. hunter's only giving enough of it to see what's happening here.